# Limit \listoffigures to several chapters of an entire book?

Tags: table-of-contents

I use book class and have several chapters in it. However, I want to limit the number of chapters that are included in `\listoffigures` to less number then there actually are chapters. How could this be done?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail, please? Do you want, for instance, that only figures in regular chapters are listed and not those in the appendices?

Comment: The document have two part, first part contains several chapters from which I want to create list of figures and tables. The second part are self contained chapters thus I don't want to have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn on and off the inclusion in the list of figures or tables with the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\part{First}

\chapter{One}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A}
\end{figure}

\part{Second}
\captionsetup{list=false}

\chapter{Two}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Not in list}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome! Who it have slipped google?! Thank you very much it did the trick!